# TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined in AngularJS and ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have the problem that whenever I press the Submit button, I get the error that     say

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined`.

I tried several times to change the names of the parameters of the request and the order of them but I still get the same error.

This is the code of the Angular JS client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <form ng-controller="auth" ng-submit="send()">
      Username : <input ng-model="username" name="username" type="text"><br>
      Password : <input ng-model="password" name="password" type="text"><br>
      <button id="mybutton" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('auth',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
          $scope.send = function(){
            var mydata = {username : $scope.username, password : $scope.password};
          $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/',
            data : mydata, //{username : $scope.username, password : $scope.password}
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
          });
        }
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for my Express JS server

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var secret = fs.readFileSync('secret.key', 'utf8');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.username + '           ' + res.body.password);
  if(req.body.username == 'foo' && req.body.password == 'bar')
  {
    var token = jwt.sign({username : 'ahmed', exp : 1440}, secret);
    res.set('token', token);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/profile.html');
  }else{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/error.html')
  }
});

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Shirna Tensei!');
});
```

Comment: You wrote `res.body.password` in the log (?)

Comment: Oh thanks, it really did the trick